# How to extract latitude and longitude from GPS

Tags: arduino-mega, gsm, gps

I want to extract longitude and latitude from GSM/GPS module and then upload it to thingspeak. I am using sim808 GSM/GPS module and AT+CGPSINF=0 to get GPS location information sentence (CGPSINF: 0,6.823375,80.001038,36.300000,20170705124133.000,0,10,0.037040,47.410000
). I want to extract longitude and latitude from it. Does anyone know how to do it? I am not an expert in programming. someone told me to use strtok. But I don't know how to do it. Does anyone have any Arduino code to do this?

I tried DFRobot SIM808 library to collect GPS data. it works like charm. But the problem was, my upload code didn't work when i was using the library to collect longitude and latitude in the same code.

This is my web upload code.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);//(2,3)


void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(2400);   // the GPRS baud rate 9600  
  Serial.begin(2400);    // the GPRS baud rate 9600

  delay(1000);

  ShowSerialData();

}

void loop()
{
      Send2Pachube();
  if (mySerial.available())
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
void Send2Pachube()
{
  mySerial.println("AT");//start with attention
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CPIN?");//check for the sim card
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CREG?");//check for registration and access technology of cell
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CGATT?");//check whether the device is attached to GPRS.0Detch,1Attch
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");//shut packet data protocol context
  delay(1000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSTATUS");// returns the current connection status
  delay(2000);

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPMUX=0"); //create multi-IP connection(0=single connection)
  delay(2000);

  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CSTT=\"hutch3g\"");//start task and setting the APN,
  delay(1000);

  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIICR");//bring up wireless connection
  delay(3000);
  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIFSR");//get local IP adress
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();



  mySerial.println("AT+CGPSINF=0");//get GPS
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSPRT=0");//starts a TCP or UDP connection
  delay(3000);

  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"api.thingspeak.com\",\"80\"");//start up the connection
  delay(6000);

  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND");//begin send data to remote server
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();

  String str="GET https://api.thingspeak.com/update?api_key=FF19NVWMPZEWX0XK&field1=100";
  mySerial.println(str);//begin send data to remote server
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println((char)26);//sending
  delay(5000);//waitting for reply, important! the time is base on the condition of internet 
  mySerial.println();

  ShowSerialData();

  mySerial.println("AT+CIPSHUT");//close the connection
  delay(100);
  ShowSerialData();
} 
void ShowSerialData()
{
  while(mySerial.available()!=0)
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

Comment: Since the library works in getting the data, maybe you should focus on getting that to work with your code.

Answer (score 1):

First rather than just dumping it to the screen store the data in a char array

```
char dataBuffer[64];
int dataCount=0;

while ( (mySerial.available()!=0) && (dataCount<63) ) {
    dataBuffer[dataCount] = mySerial.read());
    dataCount++;
}
dataBuffer[dataCount] = 0;
```

then use strtok to split the string on the : and , characters

```
char *output;
output = strtok(dataBuffer,":");
// output will now point to everything up to the first : so "CGPSINF" for gps
int field = 0;
while (output != null) {
  field++;
  output = strtok(null,",");
// output will now point to each value in turn
// for CGPSINF:0,6.823375,80.001038,36.300000,
// when field == 1 output=="0"
// when field == 2 output=="6.823375" etc...
}
```